# Have a method in a subclass accept a subclass of an argument in its parents signature

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I think it's easiest if I provide a PoC snippet instead of explaining it with words:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Dict


class A:
    a: int


class B(A):
    b: str


class Getter:
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, o: A) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        pass


class BGetter(Getter):
    def get(self, o: B) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            'a': o.a,
            'b': o.b,
        }
```

When running mypy on this code I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 of "get" is incompatible with supertype "Getter"; supertype defines the argument type as "A"
```

I understand that it wants the `get` method in `BGetter` to have the same signature as the parent one, but why if the argument is a subclass of A? Is there a way to tell mypy that this is OK and that it should accept subclasses for arguments for methods in subclasses?

Comment: This is a violation of the LSP, as now an instance of `BGetter` cannot replace instances of `Getter` wherever a `Getter` is expected. If `GBetter.get` specifically requires an instance of `B`, then it should be a different method, not an override of `Getter.get`.

Comment: For example, imagine code like `listOfGetters: List[Getter] = [...]; for x in listOfGetters: x.get(someInstanceOfA)`. `listOfGetters` could be a mix of direct instances of `Getter` and instances of `GBetter`, but `x.get(someInstanceOfA)` only type checks for some values of `x`, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across a solution, though it may be somewhat hacky for some people.

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Generic, Protocol, TypeVar


class A:
    a: int = 2


class B(A):
    b: str = 'string'


T = TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)


class Getter(Generic[T], Protocol):
    @ abstractmethod
    def get(self, o: T) -> dict[str, Any]:
        pass


class AGetter(Getter[A]):
    def get(self, o: A) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            'a': o.a,
        }


class BGetter(Getter[B]):
    def get(self, o: B) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            'a': o.a,
            'b': o.b,
        }


def fa(getter: Getter[A], o: A) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return getter.get(o)


def fb(getter: Getter[B], o: B) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return getter.get(o)


print(fa(AGetter(), A()))
print(fa(AGetter(), B()))
print(fb(BGetter(), B()))
print(fb(BGetter(), A()))  # Expected mypy error
```

Everything but the last line will pass mypy. The last line is expected to error out because BGetter expects an instance of at least B. The only place where this falls short is the following:

```py
def f(getter: Getter, o: A) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return getter.get(o)


print(f(BGetter(), A()))
```

Mypy will not complain in this scenario since both arguments are the correct type, but this will lead to a runtime failure, since `BGetter` expects to find the `b` attribute in the provided class.